# Word Connect: Find the relations if you can!

Tags: pattern, connect-wall

These 16 words can be classified into 4 groups with 4 related words in each.
What are those relations and groups?

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FROYO | SPARKLE | QUARK | NEOPRENE |
| GELATO | POLYMER | FLICKER | CUPCAKE |
| DAZZLE | ECLAIR | LATEX | KEFIR |
| TYRE | RICOTTA | DONUT | GLARE |

Comment: I've already mentioned this in a comment below - there are obvious red herrings which makes the question very ill defined as it will provide more than one answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - NEOPRENE, POLYMER, LATEX, TYRE -- Rubber Products
>  - SPARKLE,FLICKER,DAZZLE,GLARE -- Light
>  - FROYO ,CUPCAKE, ECLAIR, DONUT  -- Android Versions
>  - QUARK, GELATO, KEFIR, RICOTTA  -- Milk Products

Comment: You should really hide your answer in a spoiler tag >!  
Also two spaces in the end of a line will keep the next line on a new line. And part of the question was what's the link between them.

Comment: You should write ">!" in front of your original answer. Also, you haven't mentioned what the relations are.

Comment: specify the relation ships also :)

Comment: Sounds about right to me

Answer (score 0):

> froyo kefir quark ricotta - dairy products
>  sparkle dazzle glare flicker - words describing light
>  donut gelato cupcake eclair - desserts
>   neoprene polymer tyre latex - artificial material/product

Comment: I'm pretty sure cupcake, donut, eclair and froyo are in the same group. They're all desserts and Android version numbers(Cupcake=1.5, Donut=1.6, Eclair=2.1 and Froyo=2.2 IIRC).

Comment: @Shotstic - quite possible, it looks like there might be some red herrings.

Answer (score 0):

**Group 1:**

> Froyo, Donut, Cupcake, Eclair - Versions of Android.

**Group 2:**

> Flicker, Sparkle, Glare, Dazzle - Bright Light

**Group 3:**

> Latex, Gelato, Kefir, Ricotta - Dairy Products

**Group 4:**

> Quark, Neoprene, Polymer, Tyre - Molecules